# MATLAB how to split columns without space or operators?

Tags: matlab

i read a data from text-file with 20000 rows:

```
0000
1000
0110
0000
0110
1101
1010
0200
0011
....
```

I want to split columns to four 20000x1 Matrix. 
How can I do it? What is the code? Thanks!

Comment: without space or operators? What on earth do you mean by that?

Comment: Use [`reshape`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is appropriate here, but not in the way it is currently written. Please read [ask] and [mcve] to understand what I mean. It is currently unclear what format your data has, how you read it from the file, and what your expected output is. Thanks!

Comment: @Felthry: I mean delimiters! 
@ Ash: Thanks!
@ Cris: Ok, I try, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manipulate the data in MATLAB I would read it in in the format that you want to. Use textscan and use the format spec %1d to specify reading in one width single integer.

If there are 4 integers per row then this should work.

```
   data = textscan(fid,'%1d%1d%1d%1d')
```

The resulting data variable should be a 4x1 cell array with each cell having the column of data required.

Using the data you supplied I get

```
data =

  1×4 cell array

    {9×1 int32}    {9×1 int32}    {9×1 int32}    {9×1 int32}
```

Where for example the 2nd column is

```
>> data{2}

ans =

  9×1 int32 column vector

   0
   0
   1
   0
   1
   1
   0
   2
   0
```

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this question as follows:

The data:

```
Data = ...
["0000"
"1000"
"0110"
"0000"
"0110"
"1101"
"1010"
"0200"
"0011"];
```

Proposal for your code:

```
% Initializing variables
Colomn1 = string(zeros(length(Data),1));
Colomn2 = string(zeros(length(Data),1));
Colomn3 = string(zeros(length(Data),1));
Colomn4 = string(zeros(length(Data),1));
% Looping trough Data and extracting the columns
for i = 1:length(Data)
   DataPerRow = Data(i);
   Colomn1(i) = extractBetween(DataPerRow,1,1);
   Colomn2(i) = extractBetween(DataPerRow,2,2);
   Colomn3(i) = extractBetween(DataPerRow,3,3);
   Colomn4(i) = extractBetween(DataPerRow,4,4);
end
```

The results:

```
Column1 =
"0"
"1"
"0"
"0"
.

Column2 =   
"0"
"0"
"1"
"0"
.

Column3 =
"0"
"0"
"1"
"0"
.

Column4 =   
"0"
"0"
"0"
"0"
.
```